# Generate an abbreviation from a string in perl using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, abbreviation

I'm new to Perl...
I want to read a file in Perl. Every time I find two or more capitalized consecutive words,  how can I abbreviate them using regular expression? For example,

" A precursor to Graphical User Interface was invented by researchers at the Stanford Research Institute, led by Douglas Engelbart. They developed the use of text-based hyperlinks manipulated with a mouse for the On Line System ." wiki

the result :
" A precursor to GUI was invented by researchers at the SRI , led by DE. They developed the use of text-based hyperlinks manipulated with a mouse for the OLS ."

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 3):

Could also be done in a single pass with an expression like:

```
s/\b([A-Z])[a-z]+(?=\s+[A-Z][a-z])|\G(?!^)\s+([A-Z])[a-z]+/$1$2/g;
```

Example:

```
$_ = "A precursor to Graphical User Interface was invented by researchers at the Stanford Research Institute, led by Douglas Engelbart. They developed the use of text-based hyperlinks manipulated with a mouse for the On Line System .";

s/\b([A-Z])[a-z]+(?=\s+[A-Z][a-z])|\G(?!^)\s+([A-Z])[a-z]+/$1$2/g;

print;
```

Output:

```
A precursor to GUI was invented by researchers at the SRI, led by DE. They developed the use of text-based hyperlinks manipulated with a mouse for the OLS .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s|\b(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s+)+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\b)|$match = $&; $match =~ s/[a-z\s]+//g;$match|ge
```

The `e` modifier executes perl statements in the replacement.

Comment: Those curlies are extraneous. Your original solution was better.